# Can we create documents in multiple containers using CosmosDb stored procedure?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

my requirement is to create documents in multiple containers in cosmos Db using stored procedure. I need to create a document in a container and log that in another container. I'm using SQL API.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no, you cannot create documents in multiple containers using a stored procedure. A stored procedure is always scoped to a single container.

In fact, you can only create documents in a single logical partition inside a container using stored procedure as you have to provide a partition key value when you are executing a stored procedure.